# how to speed up imshow matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, imshow

I am trying to plot this vector in real time on my raspberry pi.
the fastest I have managed to complete a loop was 0.6 seconds.
is there a way to speed things up?

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

plot.ion()
fig = plot.figure()
vector = np.zeros((50,1))
vector[0] = 1
hi = plot.imshow(vector)
plot.show()
i = 0

while True:
        begin = time.time()
        i = i+1
        vector[i] = 1
        hi.set_data(vector)
        plot.draw()
        vector = np.zeros((50,1))
        print (time.time() - begin)
```

thank you!

Comment: Blitting is the trick.  You can get ~20-30 fps

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to implant blitting?